# How PHAR signature prevents tampering with files?

Tags: php, phar

I am wondering if it is possible to reuse a signature of a PHAR file. As it is [described in the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.manifestfile.php), each file has a manifest, which contains a lot of things which can be faked, and 4 bytes of CRC32 checksum, which is a poor choice (md5 or sha1 would be much secure), but can be faked harder than other stuff. I have doubts about the validity of checksum used by creating the signature for verifying. I mean it is slow to create a checksum by every inclusion of the phar file, but adding a manifest cache, which contains the checksum is not an option, if you want to stay secure (because it is relatively easy to modify this cache, if it is stored in the phar file). Do you know how phar packages solve this in a fast way?

Comment: The manual says it is a checksum of the file's contents, so I'm not sure what you mean by "manifest cache". Calculating such a checksum would take no time at all on modern processors, and while possible to spoof, I suspect it's intended more to detect accidental corruption (e.g. incomplete downloads) than as any sort of security. What kind of attack would you expect it to guard against?

Comment: Thinking it through, *no* file can prove it has not been tampered with on its own, since anyone tampering could equally tamper with the proof. A signature is only proof if it is distributed separately (over a more trusted channel) or is verifiable with an external cryptographic key (in which case the signature could be bundled into the file format, but that's not the case here).

Comment: For example sending modified files with the same signature. http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/forcing-a-files-crc-to-any-value

Comment: Yes, but to what end? You could equally create a brand new PHAR with a different but valid signature.

Comment: Without the private key the attacker cannot fake the signature, just the checksum... Theoretically it is possible to create a modified file with backdoors which has the same size and crc32 checksum.

Comment: What private key? I see no mention of such in the docs, just integrity checks.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.setsignaturealgorithm.php
But pls, if you don't understand the problem, don't write here.

Comment: Well pardon me for trying to help! Yes, I missed that - the documentation is a bit confusing to follow. However, I still see no mention of the manifest being signed rather than the archive.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.manifestfile.php

Comment: It creates a manifest for every file, which contains the 4byte crc32 checksum and a lot of other not relevant stuff. After that it creates a signature using the private key, and the manifest.

Comment: Here we are: "This signature is a hash calculated on the entire phar's contents, and may be used to verify the integrity of the archive" - http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.getsignature.php

Comment: Ohh sorry. I was wrong...

Comment: Or maybe not. "This signature is a hash calculated on the entire phar's contents" - This can mean, that they use for example a sha1 checksum on the whole archive, or they use the crc32 checksums of each files...

Comment: There's no mention of intermediate hashes. I think you're over-estimating the cost of calculating a secure hash over a relatively small file on a modern CPU.

Comment: Yes maybe. I know that on relatively large files it can take seconds...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is rather hard to follow, and in some places out of date, but the verification seems to be as follows:

- all files, even those in Tar or Zip format contain [a manifest](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.fileformat.manifestfile.php) with a CRC check for basic self-validation; this is not tamper-proof, but will detect things like incomplete downloads
- files in the PHAR format can also contain a signature in one of several formats [chosen by the creator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phardata.setsignaturealgorithm.php)
- as of PHAR 2.0 (PHP version unclear), the signature can also [use an OpenSSL public-private key pair](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.using.intro.php)
- this signature is [calculated on the whole contents of the archive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phar.getsignature.php), independent of the manifest, so can be trusted to detect tampering if it, or the public key, is distributed over a trusted channel

Your question talks of the speed of the signing and verifying process, and this is a key part of your suspicion that an insecure algorithm might be in play. [Wikipedia summarises the performance of SHA-256/512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Comparison_of_SHA_functions) as 200 to 300 MiB/second on an inexpensive 64-bit CPU. Since a PHAR archive is unlikely to be as large as 200MiB, and since signature verification is performed on-demand, not on every execution (at least, I think so), the fraction of a second to hash the whole file is unlikely to be an issue. (Creation of the signature can also be postponed until all files are added, so again has no requirement for higher speed.)

Comment: Yes, so based on the documentation it is hard to decide whether the signature protects the data integrity in a secure way. I guess there are no phar authors here, so I accept this as a solution. I'll try to contact the authors or find the signature checking part in the code (if it is open source). After that I'll update this answer.

Comment: PHP is entirely open source; check http://lxr.php.net if you don't want to download a copy. But I see no reason to doubt that the signature is based on the full contents of the archive, without any weaker hashes contributing.

Comment: Most things in PHP are extensions, but many are "bundled" in the main source tree: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/phar/

Comment: Added some info on speed.

Comment: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/phar/util.c#1794
If I am reading it well, the signature is based on the content of the archive file and not on the manifest, so you were right. But please check it, because I never wrote C...

Comment: I found a lib: https://github.com/koto/phar-util/blob/master/PharUtil/RemotePharVerifier.php which makes phar signiture verifying even easier. It fixes some bugs of the 2.0.0 version. I'll check it with 2.0.1 and I will come up with a similar solution.