# How to sign Phar packages and use Phar::getSignature() to validate their integrity?

Tags: php, phar

How can we sign Phar packages and use [`Phar::getSignature()`](http://php.net/manual/en/phar.getsignature.php) to verify that they are properly downloaded?

Sole purpose of signing is to verify archive's integrity once it is downloaded and loaded into another PHP application (verification is done by the second application). There's no need for any extra "protection".

Thanks.

Comment: The signature is basically used as checksum, which the phar module itself verifies on opening them. Why are you trying to replicate that? -- Alternatively: https://github.com/koto/phar-util

Comment: Idea is to display a proper error message because there's a high chance that Phar is not properly downloaded (all sort of reasons, but mainly variable configuration of servers and PHP limitations that our software runes on).

Comment: That's quite an undertaking nonetheless. The signature format and location depends on the Phar type (.phar, .zip, .tar). And there's only little documentation on which files/sections to include for generating a digest, [How PHAR signature prevents tampering with files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23592827). See also https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/phar/util.c#L1475